Laravel Passport $tokenResult is null, Alternative to Modifying vendor Folder for Rate-Limiting Middleware
I am using Laravel Passport for token authentication and facing an issue where $tokenResult is null. I suspect the default rate limit (throttle:60,1) is exceeded, so I temporarily modified the vendor\laravel\passport\routes\web.php file:
Route::post('/token', [
    'uses' => 'AccessTokenController@issueToken',
    'as' => 'token',
    'middleware' => 'throttle:300,1',
]);

However, modifying the vendor directory is not a good practice. I am looking for an alternative solution.
Current Code:
$data = [ 
    'username' => $request->mobileNo,
    'password' => $randomPassword,
    'client_id' => $oauthClient->id,
    'client_secret' => $oauthClient->secret,
    'grant_type' => 'password',
];
$request = app('request')->create('/oauth/token', 'POST', $data);
$tokenResult = json_decode(app()->handle($request)->getContent());

Instead of modifying vendor, publish Passport's routes and override them.
If dynamic configuration is needed, adjust the throttle settings in App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider
